# How to Get Product2 with their Translations in Product2DataTranslation with SOQL

Tags: soql, translation, product2

We have Product data stored in Product2 Object and its translation data in Product2DataTranslation how I can get English-translated Product Name and Descriptions of a Product2 with a single Query?